# Scrape value based on a sibling content using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have a code of the following format in HTML:

```
...
<div class="class1">
    <div class="subclass1">Text1</div>
    <div class="subclass2">Text2</div>  
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="subclass1">Text3</div>
    <div class="subclass2">Text4</div>  
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <div class="subclass1">Text5</div>
    <div class="subclass2">Text6</div>  
</div>
...
```

**How can I extract Text2 based on the Text1?**

I have several ideas, but all include complex structure with a loop and conversion between a list and bs Series.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract Text2 based on the Text1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text2 = soup.find('div', text='Text1').find_next('div').text
           # |-----find div tag-------|-get next div tag-|
```

out:

```
'Text2'
```

or:

```
soup.find('div', text='Text1').next_sibling.next_element.text
```

this is not recommended